# Dynamic binding of v-model inside v-for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

I'm trying to dynamically bind **v-model** to an **object property** inside of **array of objects**. I don't know how to do this. The goal is to select user via **Select** html tag and then print list of user's permissions (from **array of objects**) to have a possibility to change **true/false** using **checkboxes** and save changes to **object property** inside of **array of object**.

**Template:**

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedUser">
  <option value="" disabled>Select User</option>
    <option v-for="user in users" :value="user.name">{{ user.name }}</option>
  </select>
  <p>User Index: {{ getUserIndex }}</p>
  <ul v-if="getUserIndex !== null">
    <li v-for="(perm, id) in users[getUserIndex].perms">
      <span>{{ perm.status }}</span>
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**script**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    users: [
    { name: 'Alex', perms: [ 
        { status: 'active', perm: false },
      { status: 'invoice', perm: false }
      ] },
    { name: 'John', perms: [ 
        { status: 'active', perm: false },
      { status: 'invoice', perm: false }
      ] },
    { name: 'Helen', perms: [ 
        { status: 'active', perm: false },
      { status: 'invoice', perm: false }
      ] },  
    ],
    selectedUser: ''
  },
  computed: {
    getUserIndex() {
        let username = this.selectedUser;
        let index = this.users.findIndex(el => el.name === username);
      if (index == -1) {
        return null
      } else { return index }
    }
  },
})
```

I share this **JSFiddle** link because I find it difficult to explain in words.

https://jsfiddle.net/sgtmadcap/49bjwahs/141/

I need to dynamically bind v-model to every *users[someindex].perms.perm* property to be able to change it. Later I want to upload this array to firebase database with all changes. Thank you in advance! I know this is a basic thing but any help is highly appreciated! P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/cz9g8b5f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `<input type="checkbox" v-model="perm.perm">` is enough to make it work.

I would suggest a bit of refactoring and renaming though, sinde `perm.perm` shows how unintuitive your current data structure and naming is.

I'd suggest to use a `computed` property to return the `userPermissions` instead of accessing the array by index in the template.
Also consider renaming your object properties to something like `permissions` and `isAllowed` to be more clear.

```
computed: {
  ...
  userPermissions() {
    let index = this.getUserIndex()
    // TODO: handle null
    return this.users[index].permissions
  }
}
```

And in your template

```
<li v-for="p in userPermissions">
  <span>{{ p.status }}</span>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="p.isAllowed">
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should works.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    users: [{
        name: 'Alex',
        perms: [{
            status: 'active',
            perm: false
          },
          {
            status: 'invoice',
            perm: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'John',
        perms: [{
            status: 'active',
            perm: false
          },
          {
            status: 'invoice',
            perm: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Helen',
        perms: [{
            status: 'active',
            perm: false
          },
          {
            status: 'invoice',
            perm: false
          }
        ]
      },
    ],
    selectedUser: ''
  },
  computed: {
    getUserIndex() {
      let username = this.selectedUser;
      let index = this.users.findIndex(el => el.name === username);
      if (index == -1) {
        return null
      } else {
        return index
      }
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedUser">
    <option value="" disabled>Select User</option>
    <option v-for="user in users" :value="user.name">{{ user.name }}</option>
  </select>
  <p>User Index: {{ getUserIndex }}</p>
  <ul v-if="getUserIndex !== null ">
    <li v-for="(item, id) in users[getUserIndex].perms">
      <span>{{ item.status }}</span>
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="item.perm">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```